# Windows wubi installer and windows 8

Tags: 12.04, windows, previews

I want to dual boot Windows 8 Consumer Preview and Ubuntu using Wubi, but I'm a bit confused.

Do I need to partition my drive as for a Installation drive? It shows me drive C 198 GB, which is my main drive that has Windows on it. Do I pick that drive?

And is it possible to use Wubi in windows 8 CP without problems?

Answer (score 2):

> do I need to partition my drive as for a Installation drive? It gives me drive c 198GB with is my main drive that has windows on it. do I pick that drive?

No partitioning, just run the installer.

Yes select drive C:/ or whatever drive you want that has enough space.

> and is it possible to use wubi in windows 8 CP without problems?

Considering it hasn't been released yet, I don't know but you won't destroy your PC trying.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is treated as an ordinary Windows application (such as winamp, mozilla, chrome, etc.).

With Wubi you don't have to repartition your hard drive, and to remove Wubi you just uninstall it like you uninstall other applications on windows.

I haven't tried Wubi in windows 8 before, but I think it can run without problems.

Comment: That's a good point. If you should want to remove Ubuntu, _do_ uninstall it like you would other applications. Don't just delete the folder, as this will cause problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

What Wubi does, is to create a harddisk image file. Perhaps you've heard of "iso images" or "cd images"? It's the same thing, except it simulates a harddisk instead. To Windows, this is simply a large file. To Ubuntu, it's the harddisk.

In order to use a Wubi installation, you don't need to format your disk or anything like that. It's just a folder in your Windows filesystem. Whether or not it will actually work with Windows 8, I suppose will depend on what Microsoft has done to their boot loader. If there's significant changes from Windows 7, then it may not work. Otherwise it should.

One issue you should be aware of when using Wubi is that because a lot of people have dropped Windows altogether, Wubi installs aren't quite as well tested as normal Ubuntu installed directly onto your harddisk. Which drive you install it to is irrelevant to Ubuntu, except, obviously, it needs to be available so don't install to a removable drive. :)

If you do have some extra space on your drive, though, I'll always recommend a normal install. It's just as easy, though you will need to write a CD or make a bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

No. It doesn't work. While the new graphical Windows boot manager lists Ubuntu, when you click on Ubuntu it says that the OS can't be launched due to an Error, and thats because (I think) Windows boot manager only allows Windows intallations and it checks for errors.